# Get entities from datastore in Google App Engine for use in iOS app

Tags: iphone, database, google-app-engine, rest

I have a datastore on GAE that is intended to communicate with an iPhone app. I'm currently using ASIHTTPRequest for my iPhone app and using Get/Post on GAE to update and get the data. When I want to pull down the latest data from the datastore, what's the best practice to do that? Currently I'm simply using self.response.out.write in my Get on GAE with each datastore attribute. I intended on parsing that resulting string into the correct parts for storage on the iPhone. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize the relevant data in some easily parsed format such as JSON or XML, and parse that in your iphone app. Even if there were a more 'direct' method, having a well-defined interface between different components of your app is beneficial in and of itself.